# Como hacer un groupBy que ignore mayúsculas y minúsculas en laravel?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

Tengo la siguiente consulta

```
Tickets::where('status',1)->get()->groupBy('responsable');
```

El problema es que el campo 'responsable' se rellena en mayúsculas y minúsculas y quisiera que se agrupara por ejemplo 'Tienda' con 'TIENDA' y con 'tienda'

Comment: Por favor edita y agrega aquello que hayas intentado al momento

Comment: En esta respuesta de StackOverflow te enseñan como hacerlo: creando un método get que devuelva el responsable siempre en mayúsculas. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41116016/2553194 Puedes emplearlo con el campo responsable o crearte un pseudo-campo responsableMayus. Y luego aplicas el groupBy.